# React typescript prop type of concreate function component type

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have 2 function components and I would like to have definition of icon **prop** as concreate type: `<Icon />` With actual implementation I can pass into `<Message />` any function component what I don't want.
And also calling I would like to have like this:
`<Message icon={<Icon />} />`

```
import * as React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";

type Props = {
  icon: () => JSX.Element;
  text: string
}

const Message: React.FC<Props> = ({icon: Icon, text}) => {
  return <div>
    <Icon />
    {text}
  </div>
}

const Icon = () => <i>...</i>

render(<Message icon={()=><Icon />} text="Test" />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Here is demo:
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-11oqg

Comment: if `icon` is always going to be `Icon` why have that prop in the first place? If rather you would have some sort of icon type that you need to pass it through then I would think you can put in `icon: string` and then use it that way and pass it in your `Message`

Comment: Icon will be not static every time. For example: <Icon size="m" color="red" />
So it should looks like this ```<Message icon={<Icon size="m" color="red" />} />```
But now I can pass there also something like this: ```<Message icon={<div>whatever</div>} />``` So it is not restricted to type Icon

Comment: This is the only thing what I can do: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-pdhgt
But how to restrict ```icon: React.ReactNode;``` to allow only Icon component - that is what I don't know.

Comment: @KeriMarr since you said it can be anything you dont want it to restrict to `Icon` rather you want it to restrict to `icon: React.ReactNode` as pointed out by @tonco above

Comment: Yes @tonco point is better than my ()=>JSX.Element, but still I can pass there any React.ReactNode. So I'm curious if there is any change to restrict 'icon prop' to allow only component <Icon /> and do not allow <div> or some other ReactNode